# metronic theme integration in laravel

Tags: laravel, themes, integration, metronic

I have downloaded metronic_v7.0.0 and now i wanted to integrate it with laravel

i am following [this](https://keenthemes.com/metronic/?page=docs&section=laravel-integration) tutorial but in step 3 the path specified are not in my metronic folder

app.js

```
import '../demo1/tools/webpack/vendors/global';
import '../demo1/tools/webpack/scripts';
```

app.scss

```
// base style
@import "../demo1/src/sass/style";

// skins for demo1 only
@import "../demo1/src/sass/global/layout/aside/skins/dark";
@import "../demo1/src/sass/global/layout/brand/skins/dark";
@import "../demo1/src/sass/global/layout/header/skins/base/light";
@import "../demo1/src/sass/global/layout/header/skins/menu/light";
```

in metronic folder there is a theme named "html_laravel" it uses demo 1 and i have easily integrated it with [this](https://keenthemes.com/metronic/?page=docs&section=laravel-quick-start) tutorial however this "html_laravel" theme supports only demo1

what should i do if want to integrate demo2 or demo 3 ... etc into laravel

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to ask this question to the person from whom you bought the theme?

Comment: Why is the link displaying blank page? Have they removed the documentation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes contact support at https://keenthemes.com/theme-support/?envato_item_id=4021469

I understand what your are trying to do but they don't support the other themes for Laravel. See here: https://preview.themeforest.net/item/metronic-responsive-admin-dashboard-template/full_screen_preview/4021469

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a https://github.com account (if you don't have one)
2. Send request to their repository
   https://keenthemes.com/metronic/?page=github
3. Navigate to : https://github.com/KeenthemesHub/Metronic/tree/master/theme/html_laravel/demo1/skeleton

Follow the instruction and you have a clear laravel 7 + metronic installation